# Google IoT Core MQTT publish error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mqtt, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-iot

I have my own MQTT client that connect to Google IoT Core. When I send **connect** message I received **connack**, and successfully send **pingreq** and received **pingresp**, but when I send **publish** message my connection is broken and I have error:

> mqtt: User not authorized to perform this action.

My publish topic is **/devices/{device-id}/events**

Comment: Did you solve your problem? How is your code?

Comment: @Dalton, yes, I simply have set all permissions and wait some time.

Comment: Good. Did you also get some subscriber client working? I mean without using the samples provided by google, that uses their own library...

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend looking at "I'm not receiving telemetry data on Cloud Pub/Sub" in https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/troubleshooting. I suspect it may be related to the "Cloud IoT Core Service Agent" section.